# How to assign words from a file to a 2D array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to read words from a file (which has one word per line) and store these words in a 2D String array such that each row contains all the words that begins with same letter/character. But when I try to print the array all the elements are shown to be "null".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#define numberOfMappers 2

char *buffer1[10];
char *buffer2[10];
int add = 0;
int rem = 0;
int num = 0;

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_mapper = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_pooler = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *pooler (void *param);
void *mapper (void *param);
void printBuffer1();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid1;
  int i;
  if(pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, pooler, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create producer thread\n");
        exit(1);
    }
  pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
  printBuffer1();
    return 0;
}

void *pooler(void *param) {
  FILE * fp;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    buffer1[i] = line;
  }
  fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}

void printBuffer1() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    printf("%s\t", buffer1[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `char *buffer1[26][100];` -> `char buffer1[26][100];`

Comment: `getline` already terminates the string, so you don't need to do that. More serious is that `getline` doesn't allocate a new buffer if the line fits in the memory you gave it so you'll wind up with duplicated pointers.

Comment: You probably have a blank line at the end of the file. The value of all your strings is either `NULL` or that blank line. `line` referred to the correct word when you stored it, but its contents have changed meanwhile when you read further lines. You could make copies of the strings with `strdup` like so: `buffer1[r][c] = line;` (When you print strings for debugging purposes it is a good idea tu wrap them in quotes, so that you can detect empty strings and trailing spaces.)

Comment: Another problem of your code lies in how you determine the slots where to put the words. You take the next slot whan the previous word as a different staring letter, but what if there are gaps, e.g. no words in the file start with Q? Worse, what happens when the words in the file aren't sorted or are sorted case-insensitively? You will likely overflow the 26 slots. You also don't enforce the 100-string limit in each slot.

Comment: Here's a safer implementation of your problem: http://ideone.com/byQ4z8, which takes input from `stdin`. (I'd have posted an answer, but the question was already closed.)

Comment: You must `free` the allocated `line` space.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to call `getline()`.
2. `getline()` reuses or reallocates the line buffer if you pass the previous one, thus the old line gets lost. You can prevent this by clearing the `line` pointer before each call.

So, insert

```
    line = NULL, len = 0;
    if (getline(&line, &len, fp) < 0) break;
```

before

```
    buffer1[i] = line;
```